# How to connect two computers on separate networks with java sockets

Tags: java, sockets, serversocket

I've been using Sockets in java to connect computers on the same network and ObjectInputStreams and ObjectOutputStreams to send data. The code below connects the device at 192.168.0.6 to 192.168.0.5.

```
Socket connection = new Socket(InetAddress.getByName(192.168.0.5), 6789);
```

^ on 192.168.0.6

```
Socket connection = new ServerSocket(6789, 100).accept();
```

^ on 192.168.0.5

How would you connect to computers on separate networks?

Comment: If the networks are disconnected (separate), then you should connect the two networks using a router. This is not done on the application level. If the two computers can `ping` each other then just use their LAN IP's and it'll work just fine.

Comment: You would need to connect the two networks. Usually this is done with a relatively new idea involving interconnecting multiple networks into a kind of internet. To connect to these public internet resources, there are internet addresses. Your provided example appears to use non-routable private addresses, but if the networks are connected to the internet then there is probably a way to configure your router to forward a socket from the public ip into a specific host on your private network(s).

Comment: You can for forget about Java sockets until you succeed in pinging from one of your machines to the other.  This is a networking problem.  Ask your network admin for help.  They can tell you how to ping.

Comment: Technically ping uses a different transport than TCP.  (ICMP), but in most cases it's still useful for checking connectivity.